# Trouble migrating to the Notebooks API, GCP AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-ai-platform

I have been using [GCP AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs) for quite some time now as my development environment. GCP recently made it mandatory to switch all GCP AI Platform Notebooks from the Compute Engine API with the Notebooks API. [The button](https://console.cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/list/instances), Register all which registers with the Notebooks API gives me the following error:

> [Instance name]: Location us-central1-f is not found or access is unauthorized.

However, I have the permissions to make edits in this project. I have also verified that the Notebooks Instance runs as expected but I am unable to register it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notebooks API is available in ~39 locations. us-central1-f is not an available location for Notebooks API. To check available Notebooks API locations run:

```
gcloud beta notebooks locations list
```

**Restrictions**

- If current source location/zone is not available in Notebooks API you can do the following:
  [Migrate](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/registering-legacy-notebooks#migrate_a_legacy_instance_to_a_new_notebooks_instance) Legacy Instance to a valid Notebooks API location
- If instance migration is not possible, open a support Case and engage your Google Account team to discuss the business case to bring up a new Notebooks API location
- A Legacy Instance (single disk) cannot be upgraded via Notebooks API Upgrade endpoint. Need to create a new Notebooks instance (dual-disk) and migrate data.